# Is it true that $M$ is complete?

Tags: hilbert-spaces

If $H$ is a Hilbert space and $M$ is a nonempty,closed, bounded and convex subset(not necessarily a subspace)of $H$, then is it true that $M$ is complete? If it is, then can we use it without proof? I mean is it a theorem?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/244661/showing-that-if-a-subset-of-a-complete-metric-space-is-closed-it-is-also-comple

Comment: Doesn't it affect that $H$ is not a metric space?

Comment: A Hilbert space is a complete metric space with the metric induced by the inner product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every closed subset (in your case $M$) of a complete space (in your case $H$) is itself complete as a metric space.

Take a Cauchy sequence $(x_n)_{\{n\in\mathbb{N}\}}$ in $M$. This is also a Cauchy sequence in $H$, so it has some limit $x\in H$. Since $M$ is closed, this limit is in $M$, so $M$ is itself complete.