# $N$ should not be complete!!

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

The sequence ($\frac{1}{n}$) is a Cauchy sequence in $N$ but does not converge in $N$ as it converges to $0$.Then $N$ should not be complete. But $N$ is the closed subset of $R$ which is a complete metric space .Hence, $N$ should be complete and from here also [link text](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1381371/mathbbn-a-complete-metric-space-with-dx-y-x-y/1381405) Please clear my  doubt.

And thanks for help in advance.

Comment: $1/n$ is not a sequence in $\mathbb{N}$, it is a sequence in, say, $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: "The sequence (1/n) is a Cauchy sequence in N"  No, it isn't.  $\frac 1n$ is not a natural number.  So $\{\frac 1n\} \not \subset \mathbb N$ and it is *not* a "sequence in $\mathbb N$".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac 1n$ is *not* a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb N$ as $\frac 1n \not \in \mathbb N$ for any $n \ne 1$.

To be a cauchy sequence *OF NATURAL NUMBERS* there must come a point where all the terms are less than $1$ apart.  As all the terms *ARE* natural numbers[$*$] that means there comes a point where all the terms are equal. In other words the sequence is "constant  for all but  finite terms".  And such sequences *do* converge to the constant.

More formally.  If $\{m_i\} \subset \mathbb N$ is causchy so that for any $\epsilon > 0$ then there is an $M$ so that $n,p > M \implies  |m_n - m_p| < \epsilon$.  Then if $\epsilon < 1$ then there is some $M$ so that $n,p > M \implies |m_n - m_p | < 1$ which means $m_n = m_p$ for *ALL* $n,p> M$.  And $m_n = m_p = c$ for some $c \in \mathbb N$.

SO $m_i\to c$.  Yep.  It's complete.

[$*$]  That's what "being a sequence *in* $X$" means.  It means all the terms are elements of $X$.  So $\{\frac 1n\}$ must certainly is  *NOT* a sequence "in $\mathbb N$".

Comment: Thank u so much all you .I was not able to find where I was going wrong !!