# Show that $[1, \infty) \subset \mathbb{R}$ is complete

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences, complete-spaces

Assume $\mathbb{R}$ is equipped with standard Euclidean metric, I need to show that $[1, \infty)$ is a complete space, when $[1,\infty)$ is viewed as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$. However, the complete subsets of a complete space are exactly those subsets that are closed, how can $[1,\infty)$ be complete if $[1,\infty)$ is not closed?

Comment: $[1,\infty )$ is closed

Comment: @jordan A *bounded* interval is topologically closed if and only if it is a closed interval (it contains its extremal points). An unbounded interval is topologically closed if and only if it is $\Bbb R$, $[a,\infty)$ or $(-\infty,b]$.

Comment: The complement $(-\infty,1)$ is open, hence $[1,\infty)$ is closed.

Comment: [1,inf) can't be complete if [1,inf) is not closed, but since [1,inf) * is* closed, [1,inf) must be complete.  And [1,inf) *is* closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complement is open, therefore the set is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Note: There is no contradiction since $[1,\infty)$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$.

Your proof would then look something like this:
Let $[1,\infty)\subset \mathbb{R}$. We know that $\mathbb{R}$ is a complete metric space, and also that $[1,\infty)$ is closed, because its complement $(-\infty,1)$ is open. Since a closed subset of a complete metric space is complete (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/244697/188658) for a proof), it follows that $[1,\infty)$ is a complete subspace of $\mathbb{R}$.